# Querying table with an ampersand in the name

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in the process of cleaning up a MySQL database and have to make some similar changes across multiple tables. As such, I gather my list of tables

```
$query = "
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME
FROM
    information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDB' AND
    COLUMN_NAME = 'activeColumn'";
```

then iterate through each making the changes I need. The problem is that some of these tables have an ampersand in the title. I guess PHP and/or MySQL has a problem with this, as it throws this my direction

```
/* $query = "SELECT * FROM Cats&Dogs"; */
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
right syntax to use near '&Dogs' at line 1
```

I've found ways to fix this issue when you need to [insert an ampersand in to the DB](http://www.ehow.com/how_8680761_insert-ampersands-mysql.html) and even when you [have one in the WHERE clause](http://mysql.bigresource.com/ampersand-in-WHERE-Query-M9Xz7rk7.html)(truthfully, this isn't even a full solution but it's the best I found). If I enter the exact query in to MySQL without using PHP then it works.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backticks. `` SELECT * FROM `Cats&Dogs` ``.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping table name using **reverse** single quote:

```
SELECT * FROM `Cats&Dogs`;
```

Answer (score -1):

use `addslashes()` when you post input to database and use `stripslashes()` when get from datase, this will allow special characters to store and retrieve in database

Comment: -1, this does not apply to table names, another -1, `addslashes()` is not `mysql_real_escape_string()` and does not protect you and another -1, you did not answer the question.

Comment: @john yes sorry. `backticks` is the solution