# Syntax error or access violation:

Tags: laravel

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right s   yntax to use near '&beauty
>   CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL' at line 1

Hi there,
i have met a problem in my laravel project, when i tried to edit my column by migration.
I just need to change length of 'id' in table.
Here is my code`

```
class FieldChange extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('health&beauty', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id', 11)->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('health&beauty', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id', 11)->change();
        });
    }

Comment: You have an underscore as part of the name of a table? There is a circle in hell reserved to people like you :-) . Look at here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693373/querying-table-with-an-ampersand-in-the-name

Comment: ok, but is there a way to process the code, or i must rename the tables?

Comment: Just look at the answer of the post I suggested. Surround the name of the table with backticks and give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use single `` for your table name like this.

```
`health&beauty`
```